# Does ContactsContract query for the starred contacts return the "full" contact data?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

If I query content from `ContactsContract` using `CONTENT_STREQUENT_URI` (to get starred and the most frequently contacted contacts):

```
Cursor callLogsCursor = context.getContentResolver()
        .query(Contacts.CONTENT_STREQUENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

will I get all the columns that I would get using usual `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI`?

```
 Cursor callLogsCursor = context.getContentResolver()
            .query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

Docs say that:

> `CONTENT_STREQUENT_URI` is The `content://` style `URI` for this table joined with useful data from
>   `ContactsContract.Data`, filtered to include only starred contacts
>   and the most frequently contacted contacts.

But this "useful data" definition is quite vague, as for me...

Answer (score 1):

You'll get everything you'd normally get by querying `Contacts.CONTENT_URI`, plus, you can put in your projection fields from `CommonDataKinds.Phone` and `CommonDataKinds.Email` tables, and get those too.

Not sure about other `CommonDataKinds` tables, you can try adding to your projection whatever you need and check if it works or not, but make sure you test on a range of Android versions to make sure your projection is supported on all.

Comment: Thank you. I'll wait for some other answers and mark one as the accepted. Please, ping me if I forget